# "OOP"-JS - set propertie equal to function

Tags: javascript, oop

Basicly, i want "theId" to be equal to what "getId" returns. But how?

```
var Quiz = {
   getId : function() {
      var params = 1;
      return params;
   },
   theId : getId(),
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object literal can't refer to properties/methods within itself, because at the time the object literal is evaluated the object doesn't exist yet. You have to do it as a two-step process:

```
var Quiz = {
   getId : function() {
      var params = 1;
      return params;
   }
};
Quiz.theId = Quiz.getId();
```

Note that that sets `theId` to whatever `getId()` returned *at that time,* it doesn't somehow automatically update `theId` if your real-world function is more dynamic than your example and potentially returns different values each time it's called.

Alternatively if the function is declared before the object you can create both object properties at once, with one being a reference to the function and the other being the result of calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit like a duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572), but you could use a simple [getter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FWorking_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) for your property:

```
var Quiz = {
    get theID() {
        var params = 1;
        return params;
    }
};
```